# Changing the Resolution of "time" Command in Linux

Tags: linux, time, resolution

Is there any way to change the resolution (accuracy) of the reported execution time by "time" command in Linux? It already reports the execution time in milli seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like 3 digits after the zero is the maximum resolution.  If you want better resolution, I would suggest you write a wrapper in C and use `utime`  See `man -s2 utime`

If you are using bash, then the output format of the time command (a builtin function) can be set using the `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable.  See `man bash` and search for `TIMEFORMAT`

If you are using the gnu time utility, you can set the format using `time --format=` check `man time`.  In both cases, I don't see an option for higher resolution.

Comment: Thank you. So, what is your suggestion for measuring the runtime of a bunch of C applications(benchmarks) which have short runtimes??

Comment: It is not feasible to modify each one's source code to add functions like clock_gettime().

Comment: How about running the program a 1000 times and measuring how long it takes to run on average?  I.e., time the whole loop an divide by 1000.

Comment: You are right. However, the problem is that the benchmarks are going to be run on a simulation environment. Hence, we cannot afford such an overhead.